# Interchange of diagonal elements with unitary transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have a matrix:
$$\left(\begin{array}{lll}
a & 0 & 0 \\
0 & b & 0 \\
0 & 0 & c
\end{array}\right)$$
Which I want to change to:
$$\left(\begin{array}{lll}
a & 0 & 0 \\
0 & c & 0 \\
0 & 0 & b
\end{array}\right)$$
How can I do that with a unitary transformation?

Comment: What do you believe such a transformation should look like ? For instance what values should it contain ?

Comment: Your question doesn't match your example; these two matrices do not have the same columns.

Comment: If I call my matrix M, then the transformation should be be $U M U^{\dagger}$, and where $U$ consists of (negative) ones and/or the imaginary number. But I am not sure how exactly $U$ should be constructed to give the desired matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just multiply with the permutation matrix $$P=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$
as follows: $A_2=P^\top A_1 P$. Permutation matrix is unitary and orthogonal:
$$\bar P^\top P=P^\top P=I.$$

Comment: Perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ is the basis in which the first matrix $A$ is written, you have

$$\begin{cases}
A(e_2) &= b e_2\\
A(e_3) & = c e_3
\end{cases}$$

So if you exchange $e_2$ and $e_3$, you'll have the desired result.

Therefore the unitary transformation you're looking for is

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$